# How to cancel a firebase observe single event database call

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my iOS app, a user is able to add friends by searching for there unique username.

The user types the username in a textField and I have a textFieldDidChange notification which is fired every time the text changes.

Within that method I then call the Firebase method below to check if the username exists.

```
func searchFor(_ username: String) {

    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }

    let lowercaseUsername = username.lowercased()
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.child(FirebaseDatabaseBranchNames.usernames.rawValue).child(lowercaseUsername).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [unowned self](snapshot) in

        if snapshot.exists() {
            if let usernameUid = snapshot.value as? String {
                self.isUserAlreadyAFriend(ref, uid: uid, usernameUid: usernameUid)
            }
        } else {
            // username doesn't exist
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

How can I cancel this method, before performing it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you attach a listener/observer, Firebase returns a handle for that observer. You can subsequently remove the listener/observer by calling [`ref.removeObserverWithHandle()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#-removeobserverwithhandle).

So assuming you want at most one observer, you can keep the reference and observer handle in a member field of you class and then use this code in the `searchFor` method:

```
if (self.searchHandle != nil) {
    self.searchRef.removeObserverWithHandle(searchHandle)
}

self.searchRef = ref.child(FirebaseDatabaseBranchNames.usernames.rawValue).child(lowercaseUsername)
self.searchHandle = self.searchRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [unowned self](snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        if let usernameUid = snapshot.value as? String {
            self.isUserAlreadyAFriend(ref, uid: uid, usernameUid: usernameUid)
        }
    } else {
        // username doesn't exist
    }

}, withCancel: nil)
```

Be aware that you won't be saving data transfer with this though, as the most likely result is that the database client simply drops the data that it gets back from the server.

Comment: As always, thanks Frank (need to have this somewhere I can just copy and paste in :) )

Comment: Hi @Frank assume you mean't to use observe instead of observeSingleEvent in order to be able to remove it using a handle

Comment: The question was specifically about `observeSingleEvent`, so that is what I answered for. The usefulness of detaching listener in this case is fairly marginal, but it does cover a few edge cases.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to add a handler for an observeSingleEvent and didn't think you could because the observer in an observeSingleEvent is automatically removed after being used

Comment: As I said, there are edge cases where you might want to remove an `observeSingleEvent` handler. Most apps won't need this, but: if the app is not connected to the network **and** there is no cached value for the location, the `observeSingleEvent` will not fire.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, seems ``observeSingleEvent`` func returns Void. Do you think we should use the  ``-observeEventType:withBlock``?

Comment: same issue here. `observeSingleEvent` returns void. did you use an older version for your example?

Comment: The question is about `observeSingleEvent`, which obviously cannot be cancelled. I guess the only way is to use `observeEventType` etc? Yes indeed @FrankvanPuffelen seems incorrect, or at least for recent versions of Firebase. observeSingleEventType returns `void`.

Comment: It indeed looks like the API changed Jonny. In that case it seems impossible to cancel a single-event observer, and you should use a regular observer to get cancellable behavior. Note that being able to cancel a single event observer is a valid use-case, since the listener for example won't fire if the client isn't connected to the server (unless it has the data in its cache already).

Answer (score 0):

Better you add the "removeAllObservers()" after the observe single event block. It is working for me.

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().ref.child(XXXX).child(YYYYY)
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    
    }else{
    }
}) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
ref.removeAllObservers()
```